# button not disabled when disabled provided in fieldset

Tags: html, internet-explorer

i'm working on a cross browser web site, I applied

```
<fieldset disabled="disable">
```

but the button is still functions as expected , only it appears disabled but other browser like chrome disable them completely , any reason why this is happening and how to solve it??

here is a sample code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>tesying</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset disabled>
            <input type="button" value="enter" id="button" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
        var d = document.getElementById('button');
        d.onclick = function () {
            console.log("hi");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ps: I still want the disabled in the field set.

Comment: Disabling should be done at the element level, not the fieldset level, specially considering that different browsers handle DOM rendering differently.

Comment: there are other input element that has to be disabled.

Comment: Disable them individually. You shouldn't disable on a fieldset level unless you want to deal with each and every browser's way of handling DOM functionality

Answer (score 1):

In Internet Explorer, **Disabled** attribute is not working with **fieldset**.

As a work around, You can try to refer example below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script>
function disableInputs(el) {
    var el = document.getElementById('example'),
        all = el.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        all[i].disabled = true;
    }
}

</script>
<body onload="disableInputs('example')">

<fieldset>
<div id="example">
    <input type="text" name="ex1">
    <input type="text" name="ex2">
    <input type="text" name="ex3">
    <input type="button" value="submit">
</div>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in Internet Explorer:

[image]

Comment: can you explain why is it happening??

Comment: @Dark_thunder, It looks like IE provides the basic support for fieldset and because of this reason fieldset attributes are not working in IE.